Cant Install Pycham Professional with Snap
I've been trying to install pycham with snap but it seems not working.
[sudo] password for user: 
error: snap "pycharm-professional" not found

Any idea what might went wrong?
I did trying reinstalling snap but no luck, event with a fresh installtion of Ubuntu doesn't seem to be helping!

I don't know much in linux, but here is my input:
When asking the question, let us know what command you used so that we can help solve the issue.
I did look up the issue for you, if you didn't want to use snap you could just install it normally:
Answer from link:

First you have to add below mentioned repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm

Then use theses commands
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pycharm


Link to where I got answer from:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025090/trying-to-install-pycharm-with-snap-gives-error-error-snap-pycharm-community

Was using this command sudo snap install pycharm-professional --channel=2021.3/stable --classic

It would be better to edit the original question to include the command-line that failed, than just to post the failed command-line against one of the answers. Did Eranda's suggested commands allow you to install successfully?
